# Add values uniquely in Excel column

Tags: excel, validation

I want to add unique in values in a row.

Example

Column A consists of names:

```
Column A

John
Wayne
Jack
Tom
Sam
Tom <--- It should give error because tom already entered.
```

This should happen only in this column. In column B, C or any other I can add same names. Is there any way to validate one column this way in Excel? I have searched and tried validations but it did not work.

Help me here.

Comment: Try **Data Validation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No programming is required for this.

Select cell **A1** and apply *Data Validation* to it using the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

[image]

Then copy **A1** and PasteSpecialValidation downwards.

Comment: Thank you so much!